# Chart sales by percent

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, charts

I want to make a chart that gets the Quantity of the product and the sales of the product and shows the percent of sales in the chart if possible.

For example `ProductA` Qty: 100, `ProductA` sales:50. so its 50% sales.

I have this working chart now that sums all of the sales of the product but it does not show the quantity. (the quantity is from a different table called Products)

And if i get those to work i want to for example, show in chart products that are only above 50% sales or product that are only below 50% sales.

```
private void loadchartFastt()
{
    chart1.Series[0].Points.Clear();
    chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Interval = 1;
    using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cnn"].ConnectionString))
    {
        if (cnn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            cnn.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 5 ProductName, Sum(QtySold) as QtySold FROM Sales_productholder group by ProductName order by SUM(QtySold) desc", cnn); //top selling with desc

        SqlDataReader read = command.ExecuteReader();

        while (read.Read())
        {
            this.chart1.Series["Pieces Sold"].Points.AddXY(read["ProductName"], read["QtySold"]);

        }
        read.Close();

    }
}
```

Update pic base on sir Jeric's answer.
[image]

Comment: does `Sales_productholder` and `Products`  has a relationship?

Comment: Yes sir they are related by ProductID

Comment: Use a JOIN to combine the Products Table and the ProductName Table by ProductID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieved that you can try this:

1. Join the two table based on the relationship of 'ProductID'
2. perform an expression column that will get the sales percentage by doing `[Total Sold Quantity]/[Quantity] * 100`.

> Note: We must convert `sp.QtySold` and `Quantity` to float in order to
>   get the result with decimal point. Then you can enclose the expression
>   to `DECIMAL` to only show two decimal points.

3. Then add another series to show sales percentage.

Below is the sample query I made based on your scenario:
[image]

Try this code below:

```
var sql = @"SELECT TOP 5 
                sp.ProductName, 
                SUM(sp.QtySold) AS QtySold,
                p.Quantity,
                CAST((CAST(SUM(sp.QtySold) AS FLOAT) / CAST(p.Quantity AS FLOAT)) * 100 AS DECIMAL(8,2)) [SalesPercentage]
            FROM 
                Sales_productholder sp
                JOIN Products p ON (sp.ProductID = p.ProductID)
            GROUP BY 
                sp.ProductName, p.ProductID, p.Quantity
            ORDER BY 
                SUM(sp.QtySold) DESC";
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, cnn); //top selling with desc
SqlDataReader read = command.ExecuteReader();
while (read.Read())
{
    this.chart1.Series["Pieces Sold"].Points.AddXY(read["ProductName"], read["QtySold"]);
    //add another series for the sold %
    this.chart1.Series["Sold Percentage"].Points.AddXY(read["ProductName"], read["SalesPercentage"]);
}
```

Result:
[image]

You can try to download this source code for reference:
https://github.com/makubex88/SampleChartWinform

Comment: Thank you sir jerc! But i think the chart did not look quite right. I will include the pic of the chart in the question. thank you

Comment: I just realized that my question and what i want to happen is hard because quantity is deacreasing as sales in increasing.

Comment: Just check the correct variables in your `chart1` and the maximum value for the percentage is 100%, so that will be 100 in your chart

Comment: i manage to do it sir. Can you tell me how to add a where condition in the query? the condition is. where date between ... and [SalesPercentage] >50

Comment: You can use `HAVING` for condition that has an aggregated functions and `WHERE` for the date